# calculate differences in dataframe

Tags: r, mean

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
set.seed(50)
data.frame(distance=c(rep("long", 5), rep("short", 5)),
           year=rep(2002:2006),
           mean.length=rnorm(10))

   distance year mean.length
1      long 2002  0.54966989
2      long 2003 -0.84160374
3      long 2004  0.03299794
4      long 2005  0.52414971
5      long 2006 -1.72760411
6     short 2002 -0.27786453
7     short 2003  0.36082844
8     short 2004 -0.59091244
9     short 2005  0.97559055
10    short 2006 -1.44574995
```

I need to calculate the difference between in `mean.length` between `long` and `short` in each year. Whats fastest way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way using plyr:

```
set.seed(50)
df <- data.frame(distance=c(rep("long", 5),rep("short", 5)),
                 year=rep(2002:2006),
                 mean.length=rnorm(10))

library(plyr)
aggregation.fn <- function(df) {
  data.frame(year=df$year[1],
             diff=(df$mean.length[df$distance == "long"] -
                   df$mean.length[df$distance == "short"]))}
new.df <- ddply(df, "year", aggregation.fn)
```

Gives you

```
> new.df
  year       diff
1 2002  0.8275344
2 2003 -1.2024322
3 2004  0.6239104
4 2005 -0.4514408
5 2006 -0.2818542
```

A second way

```
df <- df[order(df$year, df$distance), ]
n <- dim(df)[1]
df$new.year <- c(1, df$year[2:n] != df$year[1:(n-1)])
df$diff <- c(-diff(df$mean.length), NA)
df$diff[!df$new.year] <- NA
new.df.2 <- df[!is.na(df$diff), c("year", "diff")]

all(new.df.2 == new.df)  # True
```

Comment: You can save some typing with `ddply(df,"year",summarise,val = mean.length[distance == 'long'] - mean.length[distance == 'short'])`, probably.

Comment: Cool, that works too. I didn't know about summarise, thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `tapply()` and `apply()` like this:

```
apply(
  with(x, tapply(mean.length, list(year, distance), FUN=mean)),
  1, 
  diff
)

      2002       2003       2004       2005       2006 
-0.8275344  1.2024322 -0.6239104  0.4514408  0.2818542
```

This works because `tapply` creates a tabular summary by `year` and `distance`:

```
with(x, tapply(mean.length, list(year, distance), FUN=mean))

            long      short
2002  0.54966989 -0.2778645
2003 -0.84160374  0.3608284
2004  0.03299794 -0.5909124
2005  0.52414971  0.9755906
2006 -1.72760411 -1.4457499
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you seem to have paired values and the data.frame is ordered, you can do this:

```
res <- with(DF, mean.length[distance=="long"]-mean.length[distance=="short"])
names(res) <- unique(DF$year)

#     2002       2003       2004       2005       2006 
#0.8275344 -1.2024322  0.6239104 -0.4514408 -0.2818542
```

This should be quite fast, but not as safe as the other answers as it relies on the assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

You've received some good answers for computing the specific question at hand. It may make sense for you to consider reshaping your data into a wide format. Here are two options:

```
reshape(df, direction = "wide", idvar = "year", timevar = "distance")
#---
  year mean.length.long mean.length.short
1 2002       0.54966989        -0.2778645
2 2003      -0.84160374         0.3608284
3 2004       0.03299794        -0.5909124
4 2005       0.52414971         0.9755906
5 2006      -1.72760411        -1.4457499

#package reshape2 is probably easier to use.
library(reshape2)
dcast(year ~ distance, data = df)
#---
  year        long      short
1 2002  0.54966989 -0.2778645
2 2003 -0.84160374  0.3608284
3 2004  0.03299794 -0.5909124
4 2005  0.52414971  0.9755906
5 2006 -1.72760411 -1.4457499
```

You can easily compute your new statistics now.